# How to apply Z-index to a layer in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I am new to Photoshop trying to design a web page and I was wondering is there any way to assign a "z-index" like feature from CSS to a layer to control overlapping between my images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To control stacking, you reorder layers in the **Layer Panel**. (`Window > Layers`) Simply click and drag a layer to move it above or below other layers in the panel.

[image]

There are also a number of commands to **Arrange** layers in the `Layer` Menu item which also have associated shortcuts you can use.

[image]

Reviewing the general help files or starting with some basic [Photoshop tutorials found via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Basic%20Photoshop%20Tutorial&safe=off&hl=en&biw=1202&bih=1356&site=imghp&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=JcoRVJzwD-bFigKv54DwDg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAA&dpr=1) may be of great benefit.

Comment: @Giannis, since you're new to Photoshop and European. I'd like to point out that you can change the shortcuts shown here and nearly everywhere in the menus. --- I'd suspect that at least in some European countries you can find your self with this same issue that I've always had with the fin-swe keyboards that I've used. There's this issue that when you press shortcut keys involving square brackets, it doesn't work for some reason. The best solution is to just go to the `Edit > Keyboard shortcuts...`, Find the correct menu section and replace the square brackets with something else.

Comment: I've suspected that it might have something to do with the fact that at least with the fin-swe keyboard, you already use a modifier key, when you want a square bracket: `alt+8` add `alt+9`. Changing your keyboard to US from the OS settings does help, but it's obviously not a good idea.

Comment: @Joonas Thanx, i got a book to learn the basics first.